# Magento Mysql tuning - table cache

Tags: mysql, magento

I'm trying to tune my Magento DB for optimal performance.

I'm running nginx, php-fpm and mysql on a 4GB RAM, 8CPU core virtual machine with 4GB of RAM.

I've ran the Mysql Tuning Primer and everything looks good apart from my Table Cache:

```
TABLE CACHE
Current table_open_cache = 1000 tables
Current table_definition_cache = 400 tables
You have a total of 2510 tables
You have 1000 open tables.
Current table_cache hit rate is 3%
, while 100% of your table cache is in use
You should probably increase your table_cache
You should probably increase your table_definition_cache value.
```

and from mysqltuner

```
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 9% (1K open / 10K opened)
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 0.0% (0 cached / 209 selects)
```

The relevant settings from the my.cnf file:

```
table_cache            = 1000
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size        = 64M
```

The thing is, no matter what I increase my table_cache to - it seems to be consumed almost immediately. Is this normal for Magento? It seems abnormally high?

Does anyone have any tips about what I can do to improve this?

Thanks,

Ed

Answer (score 1):

Check your MySQL config's query cache type setting:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_type

If you set it to 0 or 2 then it will either not cache any queries or only cache the ones that you have specifically asked to cache.  That means Magento would have to explicitly ask for cached query results (I'm not sure it does that).  If you set it to 1 then it will cache all queries except those that explicitly ask for no query cache.

Table cache refers to potential open file pointers.  It could be consumed rather quickly, and will just roll off unused entries as needed.  From [MySQL's documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-cache.html):

> The table_cache and max_connections system variables affect the
>   maximum number of files the server keeps open. If you increase one or
>   both of these values, you may run up against a limit imposed by your
>   operating system on the per-process number of open file descriptors.
>   Many operating systems permit you to increase the open-files limit,
>   although the method varies widely from system to system. Consult your
>   operating system documentation to determine whether it is possible to
>   increase the limit and how to do so.
>
> table_cache is related to max_connections. For example, for 200
>   concurrent running connections, you should have a table cache size of
>   at least 200 * N, where N is the maximum number of tables per join in
>   any of the queries which you execute. You must also reserve some extra
>   file descriptors for temporary tables and files.
>
> Make sure that your operating system can handle the number of open
>   file descriptors implied by the table_cache setting. If table_cache is
>   set too high, MySQL may run out of file descriptors and refuse
>   connections, fail to perform queries, and be very unreliable. You also
>   have to take into account that the MyISAM storage engine needs two
>   file descriptors for each unique open table. You can increase the
>   number of file descriptors available to MySQL using the
>   --open-files-limit startup option to mysqld. See Section C.5.2.18, “'File' Not Found and Similar Errors”.
>
> The cache of open tables is kept at a level of table_cache entries.
>   The default value is 64; this can be changed with the --table_cache
>   option to mysqld. Note that MySQL may temporarily open more tables
>   than this to execute queries.
>
> MySQL closes an unused table and removes it from the table cache under
>   the following circumstances:
>
> When the cache is full and a thread tries to open a table that is not
>   in the cache.
>
> When the cache contains more than table_cache entries and a table in
>   the cache is no longer being used by any threads.
>
> When a table flushing operation occurs. This happens when someone
>   issues a FLUSH TABLES statement or executes a mysqladmin flush-tables
>   or mysqladmin refresh command.
>
> When the table cache fills up, the server uses the following procedure
>   to locate a cache entry to use:
>
> Tables that are not currently in use are released, beginning with the
>   table least recently used.
>
> If a new table needs to be opened, but the cache is full and no tables
>   can be released, the cache is temporarily extended as necessary. When
>   the cache is in a temporarily extended state and a table goes from a
>   used to unused state, the table is closed and released from the cache.

Comment: thanks for your answer Joshua but I don't see how that explains why the table cache is consumed so quickly?

Comment: It seems that the table cache setting is not directly referring to memory as one might expect; rather, it refers to the number of connections multiplied by the number of tables if I'm understanding correctly.  See this link: http://serverfault.com/questions/78786/tuning-and-understanding-table-cache-in-mysql

Comment: P.S., I've updated my answer with a more thorough explanation.

Comment: thanks joshua - sorry for the delayed reply - just getting back to this now - I've switched on the query cache - this table_cache config is confusing as hell! I'll monitor performance over the next few hours

Comment: Thanks Ed. I agree that it can be a pain.  Optimizing MySQL is certainly not a bad idea, but you might find addressing optimizations via MemcacheD or APC to be more productive.  Check this article out: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/speeding-up-magento-with-apc-or-memcached/